# Name Object numbers work on the sheet but come out as Strings when used in macros

Tags: excel, constants, vba

I am using the Name Object to create constants that I'm using in calculations on my worksheets.  My problem is that I need to use these same constants in Macros, but can't seem to create an integer - they keep coming through as strings.

A piece of my code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'intDocRows
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INV").Names.Add Name:="intDocRows", RefersToR1C1 _
        :=16
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INV").Names("intDocRows").Comment = ""

End Sub
```

Then I need to use this value in a calculation, but it keeps coming through as "=16" instead of 16 in both of the instances below.

`ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Names("intDocRows").Value`
`ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Names("intDocRows").RefersTo`

All help is appreciated.  Thanx.
It works fine if I use it in a cell though... it's just in the Macro that I'm having issues.

Comment: @Jamie Bull
It seems I've found a solution.

    CInt(Replace(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Names("intDocRows").Value, "=", ""))

Would you agree that this is the correct way to handle it?  I'm not getting any errors, so I'm happy :D

Comment: It's not the simplest way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Names("intDocRows").Value)` in your macro code which is simpler than your method. Or even just `Evaluate(Names("intDocRows").Value)` unless you have the same name scoped on more than one of your worksheets.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :) - I learn something new every day.